# Replace semi colon (;) character in java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to truncate semi colon from both the ends of a string using this method:

```
private String truncateSemicolon(String inputString){
    String outputString=inputString;
    boolean isTruncated = false;
    Log.i(TAG, "*************I N P U T   T O  T R U N C A T E ************* "+outputString);
    while(!isTruncated){
        if(outputString.startsWith(";")){

            outputString=outputString.substring(1,outputString.length());
            Log.i(TAG, "START *************************************"+outputString);
        }
        if(outputString.endsWith(";")){

            outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()-1));
            Log.i(TAG, "************************************* END"+outputString);
        }
        if(!outputString.endsWith(";") && !outputString.startsWith(";")){
            isTruncated=true;
        }
    }       
    Log.i(TAG, "*************O U T P U T   T O  T R U N C A T E ************* "+outputString);
    return outputString;
}
```

But this truncates from beginning only.
 What is the problem??

Comment: what is the input String. Please print it over here.

Comment: Have you thought about using REGEX?

Comment: @elegant - For me, it's working totally fine.

Comment: your code is Fine ! but you may have any other character at the end after `;` that may also be a `blank space` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine you just follow a simple step:

```
String outputString=inputString.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is right

this code is remove only first ";" and last ";" is right?

it is can't remove if last ";" have space next     ex ( " ;   " )

if you wan't ignore space

using a trim() method

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is correct ! you may be getting blank space after `;` in your string

to avoid that use `trim()`

for that case try

```
if (outputString.trim().endsWith(";")) {
    outputString = outputString.substring(0,(outputString.trim().length() - 1));
    Log.i(TAG, "*************O U T P U T   T O  T R U N C A T E ************* "+outputString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to remove semicolon ';' from your string is to use **String.replaceAll()**.

String replacedString = inputString.replaceAll("^;|$;","");

Answer (score 0):

**Try this single line may make you happy**

```
String outputString=inputString.replace(";","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(outputString.startsWith(";")){

        outputString=outputString.substring(1,outputString.length());
        Log.i(TAG, "START *************************************"+outputString);
    }
    if(outputString.endsWith(";")){

        outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()-1));
        Log.i(TAG, "************************************* END"+outputString);
    }
```

For `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`  beginIndex is the beginning index, inclusive and   endIndex is the ending index, exclusive.

So change  `outputString=outputString.substring(1,(outputString.length()));` to
`outputString=outputString.substring(1,(outputString.length() - 1));`

Similarly change in second if statement

`outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()-1));` with

`outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()-2));`

So your code should be

```
    if(outputString.startsWith(";")){

        outputString=outputString.substring(1,outputString.length()-1);
        Log.i(TAG, "START *************************************"+outputString);
    }
    if(outputString.endsWith(";")){

        outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()-2));
        Log.i(TAG, "************************************* END"+outputString);
    }
```

Comment: No. this is not right. He is trying to omit the last character if outputstring endswith ';'.

Comment: There is no such line like 'outputString=outputString.substring(0,(outputString.length()));' in @elegant's code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works correctly. Performing the substring only once will make the function more efficient.

```
private String truncateSemicolon(final String inputString) {
    int startPos = inputString.startsWith(";") ? 1 : 0;
    if(inputString.endsWith(";")) {
        return inputString.substring(startPos, inputString.length() - 1);
    } else {
        return startPos == 0 ? inputString : inputString.substring(startPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple ways to achieve this**

```
String yourDesiredText= anytext.replaceAll(";$", "");

OR

yourDesiredText= yourDesiredText.replaceAll(";$", "");

OR

if (yourDesiredText.endsWith(";")) {
    yourDesiredText= yourDesiredText.substring(0, yourDesiredText.length() - 1);
}
```

> Strings are immutable. That means you can't change them.
>
> Therefore you have to either re-assign text or set it to a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is solution

```
    String str = "input_test_str";
    // inputTestStr :
    String[] arr = str.split("");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals("_")) {
            sb.append(arr[++i].toUpperCase());
        } else {
            sb.append(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).